# Error while installing obs-ndi using alien | CentOS 8

Tags: centos, alien

I've a problem.
When I tried to install [obs-ndi](https://github.com/Palakis/obs-ndi/releases/tag/4.9.1) for my [obs-studio](https://centos.pkgs.org/8/rpmfusion-free-updates-x86_64/obs-studio-25.0.6-1.el8.x86_64.rpm.html) using [alien](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/nux-dextop-x86_64/alien-8.90-3.el7.nux.noarch.rpm.html). I've got an error (I've obs-studio installed on my PC)

```
[mlodybukk@localhost Pobrane]$ sudo alien -i obs-ndi_4.9.1-1_amd64.deb 
[sudo] password for mlodybukk: 
    dpkg --no-force-overwrite -i obs-ndi_4.9.1-1_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 25 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack obs-ndi_4.9.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking obs-ndi (4.9.1-1) over (4.9.1-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of obs-ndi:
 obs-ndi depends on obs-studio (>= 25.0.7); however:
  Package obs-studio is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package obs-ndi (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 obs-ndi
Unable to install at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Alien/Package/Deb.pm line 92.
[mlodybukk@localhost Pobrane]$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this package so I don't know if my answer can help, but are you sure that obs-studio is 25.0.7 or newer?

Comment: Hi! Now I see my OBS is 25.0.6 bruh.

Comment: Grateful it helps :)